# How to delete a version of an arxiv paper but keep some of the versions?

Tags: arxiv, withdraw

I've been searching this a long time but found no answer.

Suppose I have three version

[v1] Fri, 1 Apr 2022 19:59:40 UTC (5,413 KB)

[v2] Sun, 10 Apr 2022 01:50:29 UTC (5,668 KB)

[v3] Fri, 15 Apr 2022 02:27:34 UTC (5,440 KB)

I want to keep v1 and v3, can I just delete v2?

Anyone has done that before?

Comment: You cannot.  That is the point of ArXiv.  https://arxiv.org/help/withdraw  https://arxiv.org/help/replace

Comment: interesting. what is the logics of this? version management should be fine. There are other versions there. Why limiting this function?

Comment: Archives keep things.  That is the whole point.

Comment: What if someone read and cited your v2?

Comment: I see. Then it's deleted :)

Comment: @hsh If you want to delete preprints at will, post them on your website.

Answer (score 8):

As stated in the comments by @AnonymousPhysicist, you cannot delete any versions of your paper. As the name suggests, arxiv is intended as an archive and that includes archiving and permanently making available all versions of the material. The intent of course is citation stability. E.g. if someone wants to cite your argument on page 2, then they can cite the specific version with the right page number and do not need to worry that the argument might have moved to page 3 or been replaced entirely in a later version.

The only exception to this is copyright. As a disclaimer I am no lawyer, but from what I know, if a certain revision did include someone else's material and you submitted it without permission and past the limits of fair use, then arxiv is required to remove it. Please keep in mind though that this is legal territory and do not try to abuse it. Uploading copyrighted material without permission can land you in court, as can falsely claiming that you or someone else did so.

With all this in mind, there is no need to worry about past versions. People will almost always look at the newest version only. Even if there is an error in one of the older ones, owning up to that error is better than trying to hide it. In fact, if you corrected a bigger mistake, you should state that in the comments-field for the new version, so that those who for some reason need to look at the old version know.

Answer (score 0):

You can't! That's a property of arxiv :).